# How To Create Master Detail Report In Fast Report 4 + InstantObjects

Tags: delphi, fastreport, instantobjects

How To Create Master Detail Report In Fast Report 4 + InstantObjects ? I can show report with master data but not with detail data. I'm Using FR 4, Delphi XE, and InstantObject.

Source code to display report :

```
frxDBDataset1.DataSet := (cxGridMaster.DataController.DataSource.DataSet);
frxDBDataset2.DataSet := (cxGridDetail.DataController.DataSource.DataSet);

frxReport1.DataSets.Add(DataModule1.frxDBDataset1); // Master Data
frxReport1.DataSets.Add(DataModule1.frxDBDataset2); // Detail
frxReport1.DesignReport;
```

Answer (score 2):

Before inserting the detail dataSet in your report, define the property "MasterSource" of your detail dataSet as your master data name, too define the property "MasterField"  and "IndexField" his with key field link between they.